# Find a SUBSTRING with Oracle regexp that has an exact length

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to fetch substring from a column of Oracle table.

For E.g. 
My data is
"Thanks for registering with us, your registered no.ABC34252 Confirm your availability." 
Now i want a query that will retrieve ABC34252 . Size of this registered no is fixed, but the problem is the complete text message varies in different cases.

Please Help

Comment: You should have stored ABC34252 separately, in another column. And add it to message run-time.

Comment: @jarlh : That is what I'm asking, These strings are fetched from third party and stored in table. To store ABC34252 in separate column I've asked the question.

Comment: What is the algorithm that you want to implement?  Are you looking for strings for the form "three capital letters followed by six numbers"?  Presumably, it is possible that there will be words in the text that are exactly 9 characters that are not the number you are looking for (i.e. "algorithm" is a 9 character word but you presumably don't want to match that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work irrespective of the size of the complete test message.It will pick the alphanumeric characters.

***case 1: String lenght is ----***

```
select regexp_substr('Thanksing wi no.ABC34252 Confirm your availability.','[[:alpha:]]+[[:digit:]]+' )  Output,
       length('Thanksing wi no.ABC34252 Confirm your availability.')  Stringlen
from dual;
```

***case 2: String lenght differs ----***

```
select regexp_substr('Thanksingakdakjdshsak djsahdjsahdk sa o.ABC34252 Confirm your availability.','[[:alpha:]]+[[:digit:]]+' )  Output,
        length('Thanksingakdakjdshsak djsahdjsahdk sa o.ABC34252 Confirm your availability.') Stringlen
from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Got exactly what was expected.

Comment: Both the queries are the same. I did not understand the difference.